# Retaining alpha settings in matplotlib imshow when using PdfPages for multi-page PDF export

Tags: matplotlib, alpha, pdfpages

I'm generating overlaid plots using `imshow` and printing them to a multipage pdf using `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages`. I'm setting the alpha of the background in the overlay to 0 using:

```
edge = np.ma.masked_where(edge == 0, edge)
cmap = plt.cm.winter
cmap.set_bad('g', 0)
```

And then overlaying it onto a background image with the following two imshow commands:

```
plt.imshow(back[:, :, mid], cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.imshow(edge[:, :, mid], cmap=cmap, interpolation='nearest', alpha=0.5)
```

This produces an image that renders properly if I use `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`, but not `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages.savefig()`. Specifically, the alpha information is ignored in the `imshow` call, but not the `cmap.set_bad` call, which renders properly.

Thanks, Joseph

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2517,

Comment: and can you add a bit more code so that there is a copy-pastable example to demonstrate this problem (use synthetic data).  http://www.sscce.org/  Strongly suspect the work around is to do the mapping your self, adjust the alpha and then pass imshow the rgba arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone suffering from this problem...

The solution was to update Matplotlib to the latest version. I was using the latest version of Matplotlib in the Ubuntu 12.04 repos, but I was multiple versions behind. The bug is resolved now. Thanks!